# How can i find the longest word in a tree in Java (without a loop (for, while, do ...))

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

How can I find the longest word in a tree without a loop (for, while, do ...)?

The method header is:

```
public static String longest(Node tree) {
    return "";
}
```

In the `main` is:

```
System.out.println(longest(tree)); // => tasty
```

The tree is: `f[o[C[tasty,null],F],E[null,e]] : (Pattern: %value[%left,%right])`

My first thought was:

```
String s = tree.value;
String l = tree.left.value;    
String r = tree.right.value;    
return s < l || s < r ? longest(tree.right) : s;
```

but that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm guessing you are supposed to do this recursively. Look up how to do a recursive traversal of a tree.

Comment: You say _"without a loop (if, while, do ...)"_ why does that contain `if`? An `if` has nothing to do with loop-constructs. Your `conditon ? foo : bar` in the last line is basically an `if` and would probably be considered cheating by whoever set up those restrictions.

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to write if, i mean for* :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're only recursing to the right child, but don't forget about the left subtree.

The base case for the recursion is when the function is called with a null root, in which case return null. Otherwise, get the longest strings from the left and right subtrees of the root (these may be null, so we need to coalesce) and return the longest of these two strings along with the root's string.

Here's a minimal, complete example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static String longest(TreeNode tree) {
        if (tree == null) return null;

        var strs = new ArrayList<String>();
        strs.add(longest(tree.left));
        strs.add(longest(tree.right));
        strs.add((String)tree.value);
        return Collections.max(strs, 
            Comparator.comparing(s -> s == null ? 0 : s.length()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
             a
           /   \
         aaaa   aa
         /       \
        aaa    aaaaa   

        */
        var tree = new TreeNode<String>(
            "a",
            new TreeNode<String>(
                "aaaa",
                new TreeNode<String>("aaa", null, null),
                null
            ),
            new TreeNode<String>(
                "aa",
                null,
                new TreeNode<String>("aaaaa", null, null)
            )
        );
        System.out.println(longest(tree)); // => "aaaaa"
    }
}

class TreeNode<T> {
    public T value;
    public TreeNode left;
    public TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(T value, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
}
```

You can also flatten the tree's nodes into a list and choose the longest string from there (`TreeNode` should have a custom comparator and these methods should belong to a `Tree` class, so consider this a proof of concept):

```
public static String longest(TreeNode tree) {
    var flattened = new ArrayList<String>();
    flatten(tree, flattened);
    return Collections.max(flattened, Comparator.comparing(e -> e.length()));
}

public static void flatten(TreeNode tree, ArrayList<String> result) {
    if (tree != null) {
        flatten(tree.left, result);
        result.add((String)tree.value);
        flatten(tree.right, result);
    }
}
```